# array_unique not giving the correct output

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

this give results like

> Array( [0] => 5000 [1] => 5001 [2] => 3000 [3] => 3001 [4] => 5000 )

When I use array_unique same result is obtained

> Array ( [0] => 5000 [1] => 5001 [2] => 3000 [3] => 3001 [4] => 5000 )

```
foreach($detail as $key => $value){
            array_push($zips, $value);  
            }   
}

array_unique($zips);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) does not work by reference. That means, it won't actually modify the original array, just return a new array with the respective modifications. You need to save its output to a new (or the same) variable:

```
foreach($detail as $key => $value){
    array_push($zips, $value);  
}   

$zips = array_unique($zips);
```

Read more about [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: No problem man. Read @RomanPerekhrest 's answer too in how to make it a bit more concise. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

No need `foreach` and `array_push`, just apply and save to the needed variable `$zips`:

```
$zips = array_unique(array_values($zips));
```